Is my application of optional stopping to this martingale betting strategy correct?
Suppose I start at $\frac12$ and at every step I bet $\frac12$ of my current wealth. I stop if I ever reach $\geq1$. This gives rise to a discrete-time martingale process $X_t$ ($X_0=1/2$), and if $\tau$ denotes my stopping time, the process $X_{t\wedge\tau}$ is bounded (it lies in $(1,2)$). Therefore Doob’s Optional Stopping Theorem says that $E[X_{\tau}]=E[X_0]=\frac12$. Here, if $\tau=+\infty$, $X_\tau$ is interpreted as the random variable which is the pointwise limit of $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbf Z\geq0}$. (This pointwise limit exists almost surely by Doob’s martingale convergence theorem.)
I claim that if $\tau=+\infty$, then $(X_t)_t$ converges to $0$. Indeed, if for some $t>0$ we have $X_t$ in $(0,1)$, then $X_{t+1}$ will be a distance $\geq (X_t)/2$ from $X_t$. Therefore we cannot converge to a value in $(0,1)$.
If $\tau<+\infty$, then $E[X_\tau]\geq1$. I conclude that with probability $\leq\frac12$ we exit at $1$, and with probability $\geq\frac12$ the game goes on forever and we converge to $0$.
Is my reasoning valid?

'If $\tau<\infty$ then $E[X_\tau]=1$' does not make sense to me. What you might want to do is to compute $E[X_\tau\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau<\infty\}}]$. At the same time, the argument for the convergence of $(X_n)_n$ seems to me pointwise (i.e. for fixed $\omega$), but we can only argue a.s.

Let $(Z_n)_n$ IID s.t. $P(Z_1=1)=P(Z_1=-1)=1/2$. We consider
$$X_n=X_{n-1}+Z_n\frac{X_{n-1}}{2}=X_{n-1}\bigg(1+\frac{Z_n}{2}\bigg)\implies X_n=\frac{1}{2}\prod_{1\leq k \leq n}\bigg(1+\frac{Z_k}{2}\bigg)$$
which is a nonnegative martingale. Note, by strong law of large numbers:
$$\ln(X_n)=-\ln(2)+\sum_{1\leq k \leq n}\ln\bigg(1+\frac{Z_k}{2}\bigg)\implies \ln(X_n^{1/n})\stackrel{\textrm{a.s.}}{\to}\frac{\ln(3/2)+\ln(1/2)}{2}<0$$
So $\lim_nX_n^{1/n}\in (0,1)$ (a.s.) and so $\lim_nX_n\to^{\textrm{a.s.}} 0$. Therefore, by dominated convergence
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}E[X_n\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau>n\}}]=0$$
Note $X_\tau\leq 3/2$ a.s. Therefore, by OST on $(X_{\tau\wedge n})_n$ and DCT on $E[X_\tau \mathbf{1}_{\{\tau\leq n\}}]$ we conclude that $E[X_\tau\mathbf{1}_{\{\tau<\infty\}}]=\frac{1}{2}$.

Sorry, you’re right, the statement should be ‘if $\tau<+\infty$ then $E[X_\tau] \geq1$.’ I just edited the question statement to fix this. Do you agree with this? It’s simply the definition of the stopping rule. If $\tau<+\infty$ it means we have stopped in finite time. By definition this can only happen if $X_\tau\geq1$.

@Tomo also the statement 'if $\tau<\infty$ then $E[X_\tau]\geq 1$' appears imprecise to me. The assumption states that one works on the set ${\tau<\infty}$, but the expectation $E[X_\tau]$ does not take this into account. What would make sense to me is $E[X_\tau\mathbf{1}_{{\tau<\infty}}]$.

You’re right that my syntax is imprecise. Can we instead say simply that ‘if the martingale $X_t$ stops in finite time, then $X_{T}\geq1$?’ i.e. ‘if $T<\infty$ then $X_T\geq1$.’ Thank you so much for your help with this – it is quite important to me.

@Tomo I would agree with that

Thanks, and we can also say ‘if $T=+\infty$ then $X_T = 0$ almost surely.’

Snoop: It's a lot to ask but, when you have time, would you mind explaining A) how you obtained the statement after the long arrow ( the $ln(X_{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}) = \ldots $)  and  B) I'm not clear on the very last sentence where you conclude that the expectation  $ = \frac{1}{2} $ using OST and DCT. Thanks so much and no rush.

Hello @markleeds let me know if this clears out doubts: (A) $\ln(X_n^{1/n})=\ln(X_n)/n$ so divide the rhs by $n$ and send $n\to \infty$ - the LLN implies that $\ln(X_n)/n\to E[\ln(1+Z_1/2)]$ a.s.; (B) OST gives us $1/2=E[X_{\tau\wedge n}]=E[X_\tau\mathbf{1}{{\tau\leq n}}]+E[X_n\mathbf{1}{{\tau>n}}]$.

Thanks Snoop. Now it's perfectly clear. The only thing I'm still confused about and I'm not sure if you use it anywhere but where did the $ln(\frac{3}{2})$ and the $ln(\frac{1}{2})$ come from in the last expression on the same line as the LLN.

Thanks Snoop. Now it's almost clear. The only thing I'm still confused about is where did the $ln(\frac{3}{2})$ and the $ln(\frac{1}{2})$ come from in the last expression on the same line as the LLN. I understand the use of the LLN to get $ln(\frac{X_{n}}{n})$ but not the very last expression. That expression must be what $ln(\frac{X_{n}}{n})$ converges to but I don't see it. Thanks again.

@markleeds those terms come from $E[\ln(1+Z_1/2)]$

Aaaah.  You're taking the expectation of the $Z_k$ which is straightforward since it's Bernoulli. Got it. Thanks a lot for both the explanation and your patience.
